# Doctrine2 - Specific NULL sorting

Tags: doctrine-orm

When you sort on column `a` descending, it will put all records having `a` `NULL` at the bottom, which makes sense. What I want is the following ordering when I'm sorting on attribute `a` descending:

```
a
----
NULL
NULL
5
4
3
2
1
```

I know Oracle has `NULLS_FIRST` and in MySQL you could use `ORDER BY ISNULL(a)`, but I'm wondering whether there is an elegant way to deal with this using Doctrine2 functionality only? So not using native queries, etc.

---

Answer with the help of S0pa: I fixed it using the following new function node for Doctrine2:

```
<?php
namespace MyBundle\General;

use \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;

class IsnullFunctionNode extends \Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode
{
    private $isnull;

    public function parse(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser $parser)
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);
        $this->isnull = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }
    public function getSql(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {
        return 'ISNULL('.$this->isnull->dispatch($sqlWalker).')';
    }
}
```

And connected it in Symfony2 to Doctrine2 like this (app.yml):

```
doctrine:
  orm:
    entity_managers:
      default:
        ...
        dql:
          numeric_functions:
            isnull: Diagenda\CommonBundle\General\IsnullFunctionNode
```

I can't use these functions in my `ORDER BY` clause, but by doing a `SELECT ISNULL(a) AS n_a` I can order on the `n_a` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way is to define your own DQL function, using [this tutorial](http://readthedocs.org/docs/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html). You will still need to handle different case depending on your DB management system.